# Get name of frontmost app on mac os x using c/c++

Tags: c++, c, macos

I'm looking for a way to get the name of the app in use, using c/c++ in mac os x. The only way I've found to do this is throught NSWorkspace that as I understand it, requires objetive C.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If by "pure c/c++" you mean using only standard C or C++, then no, what you want is impossible. You're going to need to use some external API.

Comment: I guess I meant using just C/C++, all examples I've found require objective C or swift. I edited my post. A way to do it before was to include ApplicationServices.h and call the GetFrontProcess function but it's now deprecated. I need something like that.